# how to chop string and random version number in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, docker, jenkins

lets say i have an artifact in Nexus named as "abc-1.0.war". Jenkins keep pulling the latest artifacts from nexus that keeps incremented for eg "abc-1.2.war, abc-1.3.war & so on" and build the Docker image via jenkins.

now i want to know how would i define the docker tag with the latest versions that is incremented each time and store in jenkins. for eg: ankur/java:1.0, ankur/java:1.1 ?

i have defined execute shell in jenkins that will delimiter the artifacts values into 2 parts (f1:f2) so that those variable values i can define into tag to acknowledge the version but it didnt work.

Please advise if there is more technique i can define

comp=$COMPONENT
echo $COMPONENT
VERSION='echo $comp | cut -d ":" -f2
ARTIFACT-ID='echo $comp | cut -d ":" -f1

Also Execute shell for Docker in jenkins:
export Dockerfile=Dockerfile
export IMG=$(DTR)/$(REPO)/$(APP_COMPONENT):$(ENVIRONMENT)-$(VERSION)-$(APP_COMPONENT)

(Note: $COMPONENT,$DTR,$REPO,$APP_COMPONENT, $ENVIRONMENT is string parameter in jenkins where i define hardcoded valued during build time"

Comment: Please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as `code/data/output/errorMsgs`. For more info see  [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstood your question. 
Assuming your `$COMPONENT` variable holds the name of the Nexus file, so something like "abc-1.2.war"
Then you can get the version numbers "1" and "2" as follows:

```
COMPONENT=abc-1.2.war
comp=$COMPONENT
tail=$(echo $comp | cut -d "-" -f2)
VERSION=$(echo $tail | cut -d "." -f1).$(echo $tail | cut -d "." -f2)
```

Note the $(...) syntax to assign the result of the cut calls to the variables.

which you can then use to build your docker file:

```
docker build -t ankur/java:$VERSION
```

Refactoring your Execute shell:

```
export Dockerfile=Dockerfile 
export IMG=$DTR/$REPO/$APP_COMPONENT:$ENVIRONMENT-$VERSION-$APP_COMPONENT
```

Notice I removed the parentheses from the variables.

Does any of this work for you?